# how to read/write text of specified charset in java

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a scenario where I have to read/write data from/into csv files. I understand that a csv can be read/written into just like a text file.

What I want to  know is, how do I handle the charset? For eg if a piece of text has to be read from a chinese language csv file, then how do I read it?

Comment: A CSV file IS a text file. Hence you have to read it with a Reader by specifying the input encoding. Your question is not very clear, what does "handle the charset" mean? What is in your question that is not already answered by @Garbage answer? Maybe you should clarify your question and/or accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myFile.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-15")); // Give your desired charset here
```